# Use "zero" timestamp in a MySQL JDBC prepared statement (in WHERE clause)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

My problem is that I don't know how to make a `java.sql.Timestamp` object representing a `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` datetime.

I have a database with a field declared like:

```
`a_field_name` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

I want to make a prepared statement deleting an entry with *zero* datetime.

Example:

```
String sql = "DELETE from `table` WHERE a_field_name = ?";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setTimestamp(1, zeroTimestamp);
```

The `zeroTimestamp` object is the problem. :)

Comment: this 'zero-date' value is for invalid date/time value and don't use NULL? how can you identify "invalid values" from "values not setted"?

Comment: Why don't you want to use NULL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A JDBC `Timestamp` object cannot represent the special *all-zeros* date of MySQL. You can use a string though:

```
String sql = "DELETE from `table` WHERE a_field_name = ?";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1, "0000-00-00 00:00:00");
```

You'll also have to add the connection property `noDatetimeStringSync=true` if you want to recover these values; otherwise the driver will throw an exception **when obtaining values** from the database.

See the full detail in the "Datetimes" section here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-installing-upgrading-3-0-to-3-1.html